# JQuery loop not picking up checked check boxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a loop which is supposed to go around four check boxes I have and for every one that's checked false, it should add one onto a count. However, it doesn't work. It seems to only loop around one checkbox. Can anybody help me find out why?

JQuery:

```
 $("#CreateUserButton").on('click', function () {
            var rt = false;
            var count = 0;
            $(".RoleCheck").each(function () {
                if ($(".RoleCheck").prop('checked') == false) {
                        count = count + 1;
                        alert("Added one");
                }
            });
            if (count == 4) {
                alert("All four been detected");
                $("#ModalErrorText").html("Error : A Role has not been selected.");
                rt = false;
            }
            $("#ErrorBox").prop('hidden', rt);
            return rt;
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="createButton">
                @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId) {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="checkbox-inline RoleCheck" />
                    @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
                }
            </div>
```

I know that it has something to do with the foreach loop in the HTML to create the select boxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute loop in `this` context, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element.

`$(".RoleCheck").prop('checked')` will always return the `checked` state of first checkbox.

```
$(".RoleCheck").each(function () {
    //this.checked can also be used
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
            count = count + 1;
            alert("Added one");
    }
});
```

However, loop can be simplified using `length` property.

```
var count = $(".RoleCheck:not(:checked)").length;
```

Comment: @AndrewKilburn, `this` refers to current element which in the each itaration

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=$(".RoleCheck").not(":checked").length
```

:checked selector can find all checked checkbox,
not() function can except some elements from an arrary of elements